# Conditional Statement Not Working With Records

Tags: function, conditional-statements, pascal, procedure

How do i display all customers who have purchased an item on a certain day, my code doesn't seem to work, ive tried implementing the code within the displayByDayPurchased procedure. Sorry if this is a simple question, i'm still new to programming.

```
type

Tday = (monday, tuesday);

    Tcustomer = record
        itemPurchased:string;
        dayPurchased: Tday;
    end;

    Tcustomers = array of Tcustomer;

function readDay(prompt:string): Tday;
var
    selection:Integer;
begin
    writeln('1. Monday');
    writeln('2. Tuesday');

    selection := ReadIntegerRange('Select day purcased (1 - 3): ', 1, 3);
    result := Tday(selection-1);
end;

function readCustomers(prompt:string):TCustomers;
var
    numOfCustomers:integer;
    i:integer;
begin
    numOfCustomers := ReadInteger('Enter number of customers: ');
    setLength(result, numOfCustomers);

    for i := 0 to high(result) do
    begin
        writeln(i);
        result[i].itemPurchased := ReadString('Item Purchased: ');
        result[i].dayPurchased := readDay(prompt);
    end;
end;

procedure displayByDayPurchased(customers:TCustomers);
var
    specific_day:integer;
begin
    specific_day := ReadInteger('Enter day to see items purchased');

    if (specific_day = customers.dayPurchased[specific_day])then
    begin

    end;
end; 

procedure Main();
var
    customer: Tcustomers;
begin
    customer := readCustomers('Read in customers');

end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my code doesn't seem to work, ive tried implementing the code within the displayByDayPurchased procedure.

Well, in the code you've posted, your `displayByDayPurchased` doesn't actually implement anything which would result in matching records being displayed, all you have is an empty `begin ... end` block:

```
if (specific_day = customers.dayPurchased[specific_day])then
begin

end;
```

and a) that doesn't correctly specify the match condition anyway and b) it will not compile because a `Tcustomers` array does not have a `dayPurchased` field ( a `Tcustomer` record does, but not the array).

Your code depends of quite a lot of things whose definitions you have not provide (`ReadString`, `ReadInteger`, `ReadIntegerRange`, etc) so it is difficult to give you a tested solution.

However an implementation of your `displayByDayPurchased` should probably look something like this:

```
procedure  displayByDayPurchased(customers:TCustomers);
var
    specific_day:integer;
    i : integer;
    ADay : Tday;
begin
    specific_day := ReadInteger('Enter day to see items purchased');
    ADay := Tday(specific_day); //  converts integer to TDay value

    for i := Low(customers) to High(Customers) do begin
      if customers[i].dayPurchased = ADay then begin
        writenln(customers[i].itemPurchased);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

I assume your `Tcustomer` record actually includes the customer's name, andx your code needs modifying to handle that.

Btw, your `function readDay(prompt:string): Tday` is **wrong**;  Because of your definition of `Tday`, the allowed values in `readDay` should be 0 and 1, because the lowest value of the `Tday` enumeration actually corresponds to zero, not 1.

Also, you did not say which Pascal compiler you are using, but most modern versions allow a call like `Tday(integerValue)` to convert an integer to an instance value of the enumeration.